# Two listView in layout without scroll

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/bag" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nicetab">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"></ImageView>
    <TextView       android:layout_width="fill_parent" style="@color/white" android:text="WAY - Where are you?" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/logintoway"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" ></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        style="@style/relbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="General Preference"
        android:id="@+id/genpref">
        </TextView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/settingsListView1"
        style="@style/listbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@id/genpref"/>

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" 
        android:id="@+id/notpref"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Notification Preference"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingsListView1">
        </TextView>


        <ListView style="@style/listbag" android:id="@+id/settingsListView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="15dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/radius" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip" 
            android:paddingTop="15dip" android:paddingBottom="15dip" 
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
            android:layout_below="@id/notpref" 
            android:scrollbars="none"
            />
            </RelativeLayout>>
      </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want display all available items each listveiw not using listview's scrollbars. For that reason I set all this in ScrollView. But what should I do here for displaying all available items. Any help will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: ListView shouldn't be added inside ScrollView.

Comment: If you don't want to use listview's scrollbars, but you should add items dynamically, use LinearLayout embedded into ScrollView and call linearLayout.addView(someItem).

Comment: I want display all available items in listview, I used ScrollView so with help of scrollview I could two list's items. So if I put it in linearLayout how could I make linearlayout scorllable

Comment: If you put LinearLayout into ScrollView, then LinearLayout and its contents will be scrollable. If you put ListView into ScrollView, that construction tends to be glitchous (because you put one scrollable into another).

Comment: Your offer is like this one right? <ScrolView> <LinearLayout> <Relativelayout> .....

Comment: I meant, drop away all ListView and switch them to LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put ListView into ScrollView: scrollable shouldn't be into another scrollable. Put LinearLayout into ScrollView and then call addView(someItem) of this LinearLayout. LinearLayout in ScrollView is a common practice in such tasks.

```
<ScrollView><RelativeLayout> some views <LinearLayout id="1" /> some views <LinearLayout id="2" /></RelativeLayout></ScrollView>
```

Otherwise:

```
<ScrollView><LinearLayout> some views <LinearLayout id="1" /> some views <LinearLayout id="2" /></LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

In that case, you will avoid "android:layout_below". And don't forget to set layout orientation as vertical.